# Valid Expression in C with Help of Macro or typedef: (x) ((x) - 1)

Tags: c, macros, expression

Can the "expression" `(x) ((x) - 1)` ever be a valid C expression with help of macro or typedef?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure it can. If we have this macro

```
#define x int
```

Then your expression becomes `(int)((int) - 1)`. It does a superfluous cast of `-1` to `int`, and then casts the result again.

Pointless, but perfectly valid.

Comment: The same will happen for any numeric type (`float`, `double`, `unsigned`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define DEC(x) ((x) - 1)

int main(void)
{
  int i = 1;

  printf("before DEC: %d\n", i);

  i = DEC(i);

  printf("after DEC: %d\n", i);
}
```

gives you:

```
 before DEC: 1
 after DEC: 0
```

Comment: I doubt it answers the OP's question. There is no _(x) ((x) - 1)_ **expression** in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @P__J__ and @Lxer Lx and book *C Traps and Pitfalls*. 
In the former question we just ask help for macro, but I found that `typedef` is also helpful.
Then I got a new answer, if we think the undefined function pointer arithmetic is ok:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void (*T)(void *);
void m(void * ok){
    printf("awesome\n");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    T x = m;
    (x) ((x) - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#define x foo

int foo(void *ptr)
{
    return (x)(x -1) ;
}
```

Comment: good, but what does this code mean? I found every time I ran it, it returned different value.

Comment: No, this is not valid C. This is a constraint violation. Pointer arithmetic is not defined for pointer to a function in standard C.